# Spurious blank equation line in a 'gather' environment

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I have the following code:

```
\begin{gather}
 u(x,t) = 0 \ \mathrm{ si\ } x = 0,  x = 1\\
\label{ex1bc}
\\
u(x,0) = \left\{
       \begin{array}{ll}
     2x,      & \mathrm{si\ } 0 \le x \le 1/2 \\
     2(1-x) & \mathrm{si\ } 1/2 \le x \le 1 \\
       \end{array}
     \right.
   \label{ex1inicial}
\end{gather}
```

That produces:

[image: a]

I would like to have that but without the blank equation 2.23. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you need is 2 `equation`s with `cases` in the second one.

Comment: Just remove the double-backslash after `x = 0,  x = 1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a spurious extra `\\` after the first equation. Remove it, and the extra line will disappear.

For the second equation, do consider using a `cases` environment; for one, the left-hand curly brace will be a bit larger.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' env. and `\text` macro
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{2}          % just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{21}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
u(x,t) = 0 \text{ si } x = 0,  x = 1 \label{ex1bc}\\
u(x,0) = \begin{cases}
            2x     & \text{si } 0   \le x \le 1/2 \\
            2(1-x) & \text{si } 1/2 \le x \le 1 \\
         \end{cases} \label{ex1inicial}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Load `amsmath`.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
u(x,t) = 0 \text{ si } x = 0,  x = 1\label{ex1bc}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u(x,0)=\begin{cases}
x,      & \text{si  $0 \le x \le 1/2$}, \\
2(1-x),  & \text{si  $1/2 \le x \le 1$.} \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since the OP uses a `gather` environment, he must have loaded the `amsmath` package (or the `mathtools` package) already.

Comment: @Mico, yes, I agree. But in case someone simply read the answer...

Comment: You may want to state explicitly somewhere that your solution to the OP's problem is to replace the `gather` environment with two consecutive `equation` environments.